# Chart for each table row SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a report and I cannot figure out how to run/group the information. I am using VS 2008 R2 SSRS reporting services.

For the report, I have a list of questions. These questions are asked by a group of people over a period of time. For each question, I need a chart that displays the answers for each person in a bar graph. For example:

How is your day?

Person 1   -------great--------|---bad--|------okay----------|

Person 2   --great--|-------bad-------|--------okay----------|

Person 3   --------great------------|--bad--|------okay------|

The above would symbolize a chart with the amount of time the person answered 'great', 'okay' or bad throughout a period of time.

My question is, how do I create such a chart (an actual chart not a text representation) in the table so that the chart will follow each question. I will have anywhere between 5-10 questions all of which need a chart displaying the results.

I am at a loss here. I don't know SSRS very well and I have been unable to create anything other than a data bar in the table.

Any help is appreciated!

SOLUTION:
I have solved the problem by using a list with a row group grouping by question. I can then add a chart into the list and format the chart accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might like sparklines and databars!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633676.aspx#DataBars

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seanboon/archive/2009/11/23/an-introduction-to-data-bars-in-sql-server-reporting-services-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: The problem is I need all the data bars to be consolidated into one chart. I am able to do it with data bars, but I need a whole chart at the end of each question with all the people in one chart rather than bars next to each person.

Comment: Can you post a sketch of what you're looking for then?  Not sure I'm understanding the situation if neither a normal bar graph nor a databar will work.

Comment: What about adding a grouping to your table on Question, having the detail rows contain person name and a databar, and then creatively formatting the sizes of the databar and table cells in such a way that they visually represent a bar graph?

Comment: http://imgur.com/0ezaeIA is an image of what I am trying to attempt. I do group my rows by question... but the problem I am having is in the second graph in my image. The user has multiple entries in the 'question' group because the answers are different so I end up with multiple data bars for one person. Does that make sense?

Comment: Or are you saying that instead of the bar being broken into 3 sections, you'd want one continuous bar per person?

Comment: I created that using a list control, grouping on Question Name, with a chart housed in the list control.  I will post the code for you in a bit when i'm back near a computer.

Comment: I do not need the code if you do not want to post it. Knowing to use a list control was enough for me to solve the problem! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Excellent news, sorry I didn't get it up sooner, life happened.

Comment: Not a problem! I am accepting this answer due to the comments. Thanks again for you input